# Using MEAN Stack for social media app and service like fiverr

Tags: node.js, design-patterns, reactjs, social-networking, mean-stack

I'm planning for an application that is a social media app with service like fiverr is integrated where user can communicate with each other and ask for advise.

Problem: What should be the best technology stack, weather it should be MEAN(Mongo, Express, Angular 2.x, Node) or MEN(Mongo, Express, React, Node).

Also I want it to be a REST web app, so that I can develop mobile apps later. So should I use some NodeJS framework like KeyStone or some generator like generator-meanjs. And what should be the directory structure or architecture for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choosing the best technology stack is up to the expertise of the group who would be working together. Since you are mentioning about MEAN I assume that you are well acquainted with Javascript. The answer to your other question of having the REST web app, Mean JS does provide you with the REST APIs (courtesy ExpressJS) while using CRUD module generators, You get that out of the box if you are going with mean.

Though all these utilities will help you get started from scratch in no time it really depends on the business logic of how you would want to capture the work flows. From what I get fiverr service seems to be a kind of free lancing website where one would show case their skill set and get hired. Unfortunately [fiverr doesn't seem to be having an API where you can integrate your service](https://www.quora.com/Does-fiverr-have-an-API).

Edit1: To build a service like fiverr you have to tie in various aspects not just the technology stack. There is business logic which hsa to be defined on what you'd want your app to acheive. For example let's assume you are doing some thing similar to fiverr, You would have to account for eCommerce stuff that would be happening. You would have to have user management built in to your app.(Mean.js does provide a few aspects of this, user signin/signup social media integration). Every thing else depends on what you'd actually want your service to acheive, All the best :)

Comment: I'll not be using fiverr, instead I'll be building a service like fiverr on this platform, that why i'm concerned about the architecture

Comment: @TalibAllauddin I have added an edit to answer your query.

Comment: Yes obviously, I'll be doing that, but I was seeking for some advise just to eliminate the DRY(Don't Repeat Yourself) thing.